# How do I get all spans created in my HTML page using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, html, textinput

I'm getting all input texts in my HTML page by using this:

```
 var inputs = data.context.find(':input');
 $('#result').text(JSON.stringify(inputs.serializeArray()));
```

Then I have an JSON string with id and value of each input text.

I'm trying to do something similar but with all my spans. I have this in my HTML file:

```
 <td class="name"><span>{%=file.name%}</span></td>
```

I can have as many `<td class="name"> ...` tags as I want. So I have to get the value of all of them and convert to an JSON string as I did with the input text above.

How can I do it?

Comment: I've tried this one: $('#result').text($('.name span').text());
but it olny returns the value of one span.. I'd like to get all of them at once

Comment: .val() will give the value of the text input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Iterate over `.name` (or specifiy deeper if necessary), build your data structure (using `data`), and then convert it to JSON. Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/tLuPC/

Below is simulating `id` if you needed to obtain that as mentioned in your post. Using `data-` attribute to store info. Otherwise you can simply just obtain the `name`.

```
var data = [],
    jsonData = null;

$('.name').each(function () {
    var item = $(this);

    data.push({
        id: item.data('id'),
        name: $('span', item).text()
    });
});

jsonData = JSON.stringify(data);

console.log(JSON.stringify(jsonData));
```

Answer (score 3):

this code snippet: `$('.name span')` will return an array of objects, so in order to get the text from each one you need to run on it as an array:

```
$('.name span').each(function(index,val){
   //do something with val
});
```

you can see a reference to this method [here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/).

Simple fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/CMdBa/1/

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `map` function to enumerate and format a collection.

```
var spanTextArray = $('td.name span').map(function(){
    return $.trim(this.innerHTML);
}).get();
```

This will output an array of file names, you could easily modify the return to output an array of key value pairs.